# how to do multitasking application in ios 4.0

Tags: ios4, multitasking

i am having application running on os3.0 i need to adopt this for ios4.0 wat are the major things i hav to take care...
how can i do existing application compatable to multitasking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all in Apple's developer documentation.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: @ceejayoz The link provided in the answer is no longer valid, can you provide a detailed description about how to do multitasking since the link is dead?